Leibniz rule and Nakahara's definition for functional derivatives with respect to Grassmann variables
In Nakahara's book "Geometry, Topology and Physics" in section 1.5.7 (I'm reading the second edition) he defines the functional derivative with respect to Grassmann variables. He does so in a similar way he defined that with respect to $c$-numbers, as
$$
\frac{\delta F[\psi(x)]}{\delta \psi(y)} = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\left\{F[\psi(x) + \epsilon \delta(x-y)] - F[\psi(x)]\right\},
\tag{1.192}
$$
where $\psi(x)$ is a Grassmann variable which depends upon a $c$-number $x$ and $\epsilon$ is a Grassmann parameter, so $\epsilon^2 = 0$ and the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ is not necessary (dividing with respect to $\epsilon$ just means expanding in $\epsilon$ the numerator and taking only the coefficient of $\epsilon$).
First of all I don't understand why $\epsilon$ should be a Grassmann variable, maybe because we're adding it to $\psi$, so when we evaluate the numerator we want $\psi + \epsilon \delta$ to be a Grassmann variable? If I'd instead consider $\epsilon$ as a real number (so $\psi + \epsilon \delta$ will no longer have a definite parity in terms of Grassmann algebra, but this should not bother us, I guess), compute the numerator and then take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ would I obtain the same result or there exists counterexamples to this?
Now, take for example the functionals:
$$
F[\psi(x)] = \int dx \psi(x), \quad G[\psi(x)] = \theta F[\psi(x)], \tag{1}
$$
where $\theta$ is a Grassmann variable, it's easy to compute the corresponding functional derivatives using the definition above:
$$
\frac{\delta F[\psi(x)]}{\delta \psi(y)} = 1, \quad \frac{\delta G[\psi(x)]}{\delta \psi(y)} = \theta, \tag{2}
$$
where the second one follows simply from the fact that in the definition we translate only $\psi$, and not $\theta$, so
$$
\frac{\delta G[\psi(x)]}{\delta \psi(y)} = \theta \frac{\delta F[\psi(x)]}{\delta \psi(y)},\tag{3}
$$
just like the result we obtain considering $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. But when I look anywhere else in books or online, it is said that we should treat the functional derivative as a standard one, meaning that, given $\psi$ and $\theta$ are Grassmann variables, we have a minus sign in the Leibniz rule:
$$
\frac{\delta G[\psi(x)]}{\delta \psi(y)} = \frac{\delta \theta}{\delta \psi(y)} F[\psi(x)] - \theta \frac{\delta F[\psi(x)]}{\delta \psi(y)} = -\theta \frac{\delta F[\psi(x)]}{\delta \psi(y)}.\tag{4}
$$
What am I missing? Is the definition given by Nakahara wrong, or not applicable in some situations?

The definition given by Nakahara is correct. Specifically:
$$
\frac{\delta G[\psi(x)]}{\delta \psi(y)} \\
=  \frac{1}{\epsilon}\{G[\psi(x) + \epsilon \delta(x-y)] - G[\psi(x)]\} \\
= \frac{1}{\epsilon}[\theta(\psi(y) + \epsilon)-\theta\psi(y)]\\
= \frac{1}{\epsilon}(\theta\epsilon)\\
= -\theta
$$
Note that $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is applied on the left of $\delta G$, therefore there is a minute sign when switching $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ and $\theta$.

Ah thanks, now I see. So, just to make things more rigorous, considering that division by Grassmann numbers is not well defined in general (as Nakahara says too), $1/\epsilon$ can alternatively be seen as the left derivative with respect to $\epsilon$.

Hint: OP seems to be missing that $\theta$ needs to pass through $\epsilon$ in eqs. (2) & (3), producing a minus.
